# Calculate the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(3n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I can't find the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(3n)!}$$

But I have no idea how to find.

Thanks for any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. A standard trick is to use
$$
\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i ,\quad \alpha^3=1,\quad 1+\alpha+\alpha^2=0,
$$ then consider
$$
e^{x}+e^{\alpha x}+e^{\alpha^2 x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+\alpha^n+\alpha^{2n}) \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Isn't the $(3n)!$ not being sync'd to the $n$ in $x^n$ still a problem here? The hint looks good but something still seems amiss. Maybe *I'm* still missing something. EDIT: Nevermind, I get it now.